# How to set parallel DIVs?

Tags: html, css

I want to have 3  aligned parallel to each other. I have seen few examples over internet but somehow they are not working for me. My html file is follows:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1" />
<script type="text/css">
 #root {
    background-color: #eee;
}

#left_side {
    float: left;
}

#center_s {
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    width: 65px;
    background-color: #ccc;
}

#right_side {
    float: right;
}


</script>

</head>

<body>

<div id="root">
    <div id="left_side">LEFT</div>
    <div id="right_side">RIGHT</div>
    <div id="center_s">CENTER</div>
</div>



</body>
</html>
```

Thanks :)

Comment: Looks fine to me. What's wrong with it? http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/2wmEt/

Comment: How is it "not working", and which browser are you using?

Comment: @j08691: I dont't know what is going wrong, I just simply created a a html file on notpad and pasted this. Have opened this on firefox, chrome...it just display LEFT RIGHT CENTER written vertically one after another

Comment: Ah I see the problem, you're CSS `<style>` tags are incorrectly in your code as `<script>` tags.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

not script. write style instead of script. there is syntax error. like this.

```
<style type="text/css">
 #root {
   background-color: #eee;
 }

#left_side {
float: left;
 }

#center_s {
margin-left: auto;
margin-right: auto;
width: 65px;
background-color: #ccc;
}

#right_side {
float: right;
}


</style>
```

Comment: This method doesn't fix the issue that the divs are not displayed in the order they are in the code. It also doesn't declare widths on all the divs.

Answer (score 2):

If you are just trying to make 3 columns then just float them all left:

```
.wrapper {
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 960px;
}

.column {
       float: left;
       width: 33%;
}
```

HTML:

```
<div class="wrapper">
        <div class="column">left</div>
        <div class="column">center</div>
        <div class="column">right</div>
</div>
```

Then just clearfix the wrapper and you're done. This is also better because its good practice to have everything in your html appear on screen in the order that it is in your code. Using your method the center column is actually after the right column, which you want to avoid.

Answer (score 0):

```
<style type="text/css">
    #left_side {
        float: left;
        width: 32%;
    }

    #center_s {
        margin: 0 auto;
        width: 32%;
        background-color: #ccc;
    }

    #right_side {
        float: right;
        width: 32%;
    }
</style>
```

Answer (score 0):

A few things 
A first, your tags for the css should be 'style', not 'script'

- you also have to declare the width of the DIVs

- have them all float left

- put the in the order you want from left to right

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1" />
<style type="text/css">
 #root {
    background-color: #eee;
}

#left_side {
    float: left;
    width:65px;
}

#center_s {
    float:left;
    width:65px;
    background-color: #ccc;
}

#right_side {
    float: left:
    width:65px;
}
.clear{clear:both;}


</style>

</head>

<body>

<div id="root">
    <div id="left_side">LEFT</div>
    <div id="center_s">CENTER</div>
    <div id="right_side">RIGHT</div>
</div>
<div class="clear"></div>



</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use flex-container on outer div and flex-item on inner div's. Follow https://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_flexbox.asp for any further references.